# What is the type of Java class that exposes public variables?

Tags: java

There's a term that's used to describe a type of class that exposes its member variables as public.  Does someone know what I'm talking about?  I think the term hinted at not a kind of design pattern, but it did describe why the class is used that way.

If you would like an example...

```
public class HoldsLotsOfStuff {
   public String forgetMeNot;
   public String anotherThingToRemember;
   public int size;
   // etc.
}
```

And then instead of using accessor methods, you would just do this (I understand it's not recommended, btw):

```
stuffHolder = new HoldsLotsOfStuff();
stuffHolder.size = 10;
stuffHolder.forgetMeNot = "flowering plants lalala";
```

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like an imitation of a C `struct`.

Comment: DTO?  Value object?  Any given source could call it any number of things.  I'm not aware of a single official term.

Comment: The type of Java class that exposes public variables is usually referred to as "a bad idea."

Comment: ... or [`Holder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/ObjectHolder.html).

Comment: It's NAB. Not a Bean.

Comment: Variations of ["Plain Old Data" classes](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30297/is-there-any-reason-to-use-plain-old-data-classes) come to mind.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  @KevinKrumwiede, you had a really good idea.  Yes, I suppose writing it that way, is with the intention of a C structure.  There is a term for it.  When someone nails it, I'll flag it as the answer.

Comment: Categorical opposition to struct-like classes in Java is quite narrow minded. Horses for courses. http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=256

Answer (score 1):

Josh Bloch referred to classes which:

- may or may not have an explicit constructor
- expose instance fields
- are used for packaging convenience, usually with package-private accessibility (or narrower)

as **degenerate classes** in Effective Java, 2nd Ed.

Comment: The _only_ time Bloch uses the word "degenerate" in this context is here: "You may be tempted to write degenerate classes that serve no purpose other than to group instance fields" (p. 71). He is not defining "degenerate classes" as a reusable, general term: he's just using the adjective "degenerate" in a technical sense (definition: "lacking some property, order, or distinctness of structure previously or usually present, in particular"). I wouldn't call a class degenerate and expect anyone to know what I'm talking about offhand.

Comment: *"Josh Bloch referred to [such] classes ... as degenerate classes...."* What did you think that I had meant to say?

Comment: @scottb good for referencing Josh Block.  "degenerate" isn't the term I remember.  I'll have a look at the book.  Thanks!